# Setting the value of an object through Jquery Each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to iterate through an object.key (newPickup) and set the value of object.key equal to the value specified in a form. I can get through to the end without throwing any errors however, when i call the object all items are undefined. I set up a fiddle with it already loaded and I'm hoping one of you talented magnificos can let me know where I messed up. Thanks in advance.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinmota/X7MW6/

```
<button id="startPickup">Schedule Pickup</button>
<div id="pickupWrap"></div>


function Pickup(pickupDate, clinicName, phoneNumber, qtySpec, fedexConfirm){
        this.pickupDate = pickupDate;
        this.clinicName = clinicName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.qtySpec = qtySpec;
        this.fedexConfirm=fedexConfirm;
    }
//The Pickup Object
var newPickup = new Pickup();

//Click the button to make the form 
$("#startPickup").click(function(){
    //Empty if exists
    $("#pickupWrap").empty();
    //Make the inputs
    $.each(newPickup, function(key,value){
        $('#pickupWrap').append("<label for=\""+key+"\">"+key+": </label><input type=\"text\" id=\""+key+"\" class=\"pickupInput\"><br>");
    });
    //Make the button
    $('#pickupWrap').append("<button id='submitPickup'>Submit Pickup</button");

    //Capture the form inputs from pickup
    $("#submitPickup").click(function(){
    console.log("click");

    //Get Values and Indexes
    $('.pickupInput').each(function(){
        var pickupIndex = $(this).attr("id");
        var pickupValue =$(this).val();

        console.log(pickupIndex+" | "+ pickupValue);

        //Set newPickup to appropriate value
        $.each(newPickup, function(key, value){
            if (key === pickupIndex) {
                console.log("we have a match");
                value = pickupValue;
            };
        })
    });
    console.log(newPickup);

});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value = pickupValue` isn't what you want, you need to specify the `object[key]` and set that:

```
$.each(newPickup, function(key, value){
    if (key === pickupIndex) {
        console.log("we have a match");
        newPickup[key] = pickupValue;
    };
})
```